# Print array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I've an array of hashes

Eg:

```
hash = [{"a"=>"apple", "b"=>"ball", "c"=>"cat"},
{"d"=>"dog", "e"=>"eagle", "f"=>"fly"}]
```

I would like to have the values printed in a loop.

Output expected is:

```
apple  
ball  
cat  
dog  
eagle  
fly
```

I've tried

```rb
hash.each do |each_hash|
  each_hash do |each_hash_element|
    each_hash_element do |k,v|
      puts "${v}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `arr.each { |h| puts h.values }` is all you need, where `arr` is your array of hashes. (I cannot bring myself to name an array `hash`. :-) That will give you one value on each of six lines.

Comment: Problem with your code is in `each_hash do` and `each_hash_element do`. Those are not methods, but are used in code as such (you pass them a block)

Comment: Another problem is `${v}`.

Comment: `${x}` is JavaScript. `#{x}` is the equivalent in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to first get an array of all the values, then print that.

```
puts hash.flat_map(&:values)
```

[`#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) maps the array values and concatenates the result of each block (flatting the whole thing by one level).

```
hash.map(&:values) #=> [["apple", "ball", "cat"], ["dog", "eagle", "fly"]]
hash.flat_map(&:values) #=> ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "eagle", "fly"]
```

In this scenario `puts hash.map(&:values)` would also work, but I personally find the use of `#flat_map` more fitting.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that hash keys are unique.

You can merge all hashes with [reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) method and prints all values like this:

```
puts hash.reduce({}, :merge).values
```

Comment: You can omit the default value in this case. But overall, the merge approach may cause some values to be not printed. I personally wouldn't do this.

Comment: Maybe put that assumption in front then?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the coding style the same, a working version looks like this:

```
array.each do |hash| # I'll rename the hash array to "array" to avoid confusion.
  hash.each_value do |value| # or: hash.each do |key, value|
    puts value
  end
end
```

This loops through the array of hashes and loops through the values for each hash.

The issue with your current code is that `each_hash` is an hash element and not a method. You should invoke the [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html#method-i-each) or [`each_value`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) method for each such element.

Comment: It's worth putting the fixed code first and the busted code second.

Comment: @tadman Why isn't it better to first explain what is wrong with the current code before providing a solution? Or do you mean merge this with my other answer?

Comment: I mostly mean explain the fix first, that's what people are going to look at when trying to find an answer, and then explain the issues second. At a glance this looks like a repeat of the original question. I think this answer would be fine without the repeat of the code, your explanation does all the necessary work.

Answer (score 0):

First you ask about an array with two hashes in it.

```sh
hash = [{"a"=>"apple", "b"=>"ball", "c"=>"cat"},
{"d"=>"dog", "e"=>"eagle", "f"=>"fly"}]
```

In the following I call it an array ...

```rb
array = [{"a"=>"apple", "b"=>"ball", "c"=>"cat"},
{"d"=>"dog", "e"=>"eagle", "f"=>"fly"}]
```

Now you have to iterate each hash in your array and print each value of that hash, while leaving the keys off

```rb
array.each { |hash| puts hash.values }
```

P.S. this solution is shameless stolen from @Cary Swoveland